# Why Localization is not working in my asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, localization

I created 2 resource files, one for English (`Resource.en.resx`) and another for Persian (`Resource.per.resx`) in `App_LocalResources` folder.

I have attached them to my server control (Label1), this way:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" 
           meta:resourceKey="Label1">
</asp:Label>
```

and Page header like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Persian.aspx.cs" 
    Inherits="Persian" Culture="auto:en-US" UICulture="auto" %>
```

After browsing in Google chrome I added 2 languages `Us English` and `Persian` and set Persian to top priority.

But it still displays in English not Persian, why? I am using VS 2013 and .net 4.5.

Comment: One wild guess: the language code for Persian is `fa` (Farsi), not `per`. Try renaming your resx file to `Resource.fa.resx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One wild guess: the language code for Persian is fa (Farsi), not per. Try renaming your resx file to Resource.fa.resx